# How do I use commas to "add" strings together in a return statement?

Tags: python, string

Let's say I want to add these strings together: `"I"` `"use"` `"Python"`

Firstly, I could concatenate them using the + sign like this:

```
print("I " + "use " + "Python")
```

But that is bulky and wastes a lot of time, especially when you need to combine a lot of strings. Also, note that I embedded the spaces into the string, whereas I usually have to use variables, meaning that I have to add spaces separately, which is an even bigger pain.

Secondly, there is a way to add with commas:

```
print("I", "use", "Python")
```

This is what I want, however this has a caveat. It doesn't seem to work in return functions.

```
def function():
  return "I", "use", "Python"
print(function())
```

This returns a tuple, instead of the string I want, which means that **sigh**, I have to use the boring plus sign concatenation. This sucks up tons of time because I need to continuously add spaces.

So back to the main question, how do I use this method in a return statement?

Comment: Mind explaining how `"I" + "use" + "Python"` is worse than `"I", "use", "Python"`? Seems about the same number of characters to me

Comment: What makes you think concatenating strings with `+` wastes time? And why do you think `,` doesn't waste time? (`,` doesn't concatenate strings at all, by the way.)

Comment: @Chase In a print statement you need to add spaces manually if you use `+` signs.

Comment: Note that `,` does not "concatenate" strings. `print` is a function, guess what `,` does in a function - that's right, it separates arguments. That's all it does there. It just so happens that the `print` function concatenates all its arguments with a space. Same way the answer in the linked question does.

Comment: As others already said string concatenation doesn't take any longer time in python. However in pypy3 it does take almost O(n) time, so better watch it there pypy users!

Comment: Did you mean: `print(*function())`?

Comment: Hi guys, what I meant was that it didn't work when I tried to do it in a return statement, as you can see in the last one. Also, in return statements, you need to add a space like every other word, which takes forever when you have a lot of words, and it seems like everyone is glossing over the "in a function part", which I will reword. Sorry if the question was poorly worded.

Comment: Also, i didn't mean how long it takes to run, I meant how long it takes to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `f-string`s if you are on Python3.6+ or format your strings with `.format`.

```
def foo(name, age):
    return f'{name} is {age} years old.'

def bar(name, age):
    return '{} is {} years old'.format(name, age)

>>> foo('Ben', 25)
'Ben is 25 years old.'
>>> bar('Tom', 20)
'Tom is 20 years old'
```

If you have list of strings that you need to join with some character, use `.join`

```
>>> my_list = ['I', 'love', 'Python']
>>> ' '.join(my_list)
'I love Python'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s1 = 'I'
s2 = 'use'
s3 = 'python'

def function(*strings):
    x = ''
    for s in strings:
        x += s + ' '

    return x

print(function(s1,s2,s3))
```

Comment: This sticks an extra space on the end of the string, and aside from that bug, is a slow and unnecessary reimplementation of `''.join`.

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_